# Angularjs - use $watch on an element with no ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, recaptcha

I am trying to get recaptcha working (cleany) with AngularJS.

The recaptcha is being created in my directive. With a callback function, I am trying to $watch for any changes in the inputs (recaptcha_challenge_field, recaptcha_response_field)

I can pass values to the scope :

```
scope.recaptcha_challenge_field = "value_taken_from_input_after_creation"
```

My problem is that the recaptcha code is being created without me so I can not add a ng-model to those inputs. So when I do a

```
scope.$watch('recaptcha_response_field', function(newValue, oldValue) { 
console.log('recaptcha_response_field ' + newValue); 
});
```

Nothing happens because obviously the scope.recaptcha_challenge_field is not linked to the

```
<input name="recaptcha_response_field" id="recaptcha_response_field" type="text">
```

My ideas :

1. Add dynamically a ng-model to my inputs but I can't figure that one out
2. bind my values to the input element and watch them

Open to any suggestion.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing which recapthca library you are using, I can only shoot in the dark. But what I would do is

1. Get a `var recaptchaElement = angular.element(...)` reference to the recaptcha
2. Add ng-model to the text input using `.attr('ng-model', 'myProp')`
3. Call $compile on the element so angular knows about it: `$compile(recaptchaElement)(scope)`

Ideally this should all be in a directive. If you make a http://plnkr.co/ I can help more.

Comment: You are a genius !!! I am kind of new with AngularJS and didn't know the compile. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I just started using it with jquery.svg recently. Its really helpful to "inform" angular about things.

Comment: Done. Sorry, discovering how to actively use stackoverflow as well :p