# AngularJS - Watch the creation of an input element

Tags: angularjs

I am working on making repatcha (www.google.com/recaptcha) work with angularjs.

I am running into a problem. Every time the refresh button is clicked, a new image appears but it destroy the  to recreate a new one with a new key.

My problem is that I was actually listening to that input thanks to a ng-model that I add (thanks to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17702950/angularjs-use-watch-on-an-element-with-no-ng-model) and Jason) but because the element is destroyed, my watch does not work.

Ideas :

1. Listen to the creation of a child of an element
2. Have another field that get updated with the number of children that another element has and watch it's value.

Other suggestions welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is looking, this solution worked for me :
http://www.brandonturner.net/blog/2009/02/reload_recaptcha_with_error/

I still can't find how to watch for new created child (unless I used livequery which is time consuming) but the hack above works for reCaptcha.

The other solution was to delay whatever I had to do by a second so the image would be loaded but it was not really "safe" to do so.